# How to add/replace character in the last index of a string in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a data like this:

> "[-8.390865416667355, 115.23490905761719],[-8.483238563913513,
>   115.19783020019531],[-8.504970203442133, 115.40382385253906]"

I want to add character "[" in the first index of my string value and "]" in my last index. But i dont know how to insert the character in the last index of my string value so my string would be appear like this:

> "[[-8.390865416667355, 115.23490905761719],[-8.483238563913513,
>   115.19783020019531],[-8.504970203442133, 115.40382385253906]]"

Comment: `$string = "[$string]";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just concatenate, like so:

```
$str = "[-8.390865416667355, 115.23490905761719],[-8.483238563913513, 115.19783020019531],[-8.504970203442133, 115.40382385253906]";

$new_str = "[".$str."]";

echo $new_str;
```